# What is "Easy mode" (during initial phone setup) and are there any problems with it?

Tags: samsung, settings

I just got a new Samsung Galaxy Core Duos running Android 4.1.2, and put a new SIM card in it. The phone has taken me through some initial setup screens for a Samsung account, Gmail account, and name, and is now asking whether I want to enable "Easy mode", for which it says "Easy mode helps you to use your device more easily with the easy widgets feature and the ability to customise the font size."

Does anyone know more detail about the difference it makes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary purpose of Easy Mode is to make the customization and use of a smart phone simpler and easier (usually for a first-time smartphone user or non-techy user). Easy Mode Vs Normal Mode for Android is quite similar to Apple vs Android --> Apple is often simpler, but less customizable.

If you just want to use your phone, Easy Mode will be easier for you. You won't have all of the same home screen customization options (but then again, you might not need them). Easy mode gives you 3 default home screens, a simpler settings menu, and a simpler camera interface.

If you love customizing the crap out of your phone, don't use easy mode. You'll then enjoy a full settings menu, fully customizable home screens, the full camera interface, and more.

Here are some resources I found for you on google ;)
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/howtoguide/N0000003/10091/120408
http://www.digit.in/mobile-phones/understanding-easy-mode-on-the-samsung-galaxy-s4-14698.html